# Dropdown that overrides flatlist column count

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

(My actual questions are at the bottom is you just want to jump there, rest is context)

I'm trying to create something that looks like the following (image from my figma):

[image]

when a chapter is clicked, a dropdown appears with your page of quick notes. as you can see, it takes up the full width of the two columns as opposed to just one.

I was able to get this far with code(note clicking a chapter doesn't do anything right now, that's why I'm here):

[image]

This is the FlatList Code:

```
<FlatList
  contentContainerStyle={{
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginVertical: 10,
    minHeight: 200,
  }}
  data={notes}
  numColumns={2}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.key}
  ListFooterComponent={() => <AddNoteFooter onPress={addSpecificNote} />}
  renderItem={({ item }) => {
    let openState;
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={null} style={styles.flastliststyle}>
          <Text style={styles.flastlistItemText}>{item.note}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }}
/>
```

**so In short my question is:**

How can I make a dropdown of this nature, and how tf do I make it so that the ListFooterComponent is listening to the column positioning instead of being centered.

Please help, this makes me very sad. I don't want to be sad.